# Linkedin: When I write a url, an image appears, and I don´t want to show it

Tags: linkedin-api

I´m administrator of the linkedin perfil of the company where I work. On the publication panel, I write a url, and suddenly, an image appears.

Why does that image appear? How could I change it? Should I change it in linkedin or in the web? How could I avoid that the image is shown in linkedin?

For example: If I write https://url.com/subpage, the panel shows an image, and I don´t want to show that image, but another one does.

If I write https://url.com/anothersubpage, no image is shown. And I´d like to show a customize image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The questions were resolved.
In the linkedin panel, I must make sure that the source code complies with the Open Graph Protocol (OGP). So I have to change the og tags.